# Change Image Resource Inside Of Div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change Image Resource Inside of Div.

I'm trying with below codes, but not working with error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: buttonShape[i].getElementById is not a function
```

```
<div class='about-nav'>
   <div class='btn-shape'>
      <img src='model/png/1.png' id='btn-icon' onClick='callSlide(1)'>
   </div>
   <div class='btn-shape'>
      <img src='model/png/1.png' id='btn-icon' onClick='callSlide(2)'>
   </div>
</div>
```

```js
function callSlide(n)
{

    var slideIndex=n;

    let btnShapeGray = ['icon-vision-gr.png', 'icon-genre-gr.png'];

    let btnShapeColor = ['icon-vision-violet.png', 'icon-genre-vi.png'];

    let buttonShape = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-shape');

    for(let i = 0; i < buttonShape.length; i++)
    {
        let target = buttonShape[i].getElementById('btn-icon');
    //  target.src = "model/png/Nav/Gray"+btnShapeGray[i];
    }

    let target = buttonShape[slideIndex-1].getElementById('btn-icon');
    target.src = "model/png/Nav/Color"+btnShapeColor[slideIndex-1];
}
```

How can I change it??

Thanks.

Comment: getElementById is defined on document, not element. eg : document.getElementById() will work, but not div.getElementById()

Comment: let target = buttonShape[i].getElementsByTagName('img')[0];

You'll be able to use this code instead of getElementById on your div

Comment: JS Bin : https://jsbin.com/bipomozulu/edit?html,js,output
Pls do have a look here as well

Comment: You have elements with duplicate ids. [Id **must** be unique](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) for the document. If they are not unique, they are not id's, use class or data attributes instead.